# Combine multiple dylib in to single framework for iOS using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods, dylib, dynamic-library

I have three libraries being independently developed and built as .dylib. I need to combine all of these libraries into a single .framework using Cocoapods.

I have tried using vendored_libraries in podspec for cocoapods but it is not even recognizing the presence of that option. I figure there are still some configuration options missing.

Any help or direction would be great

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/grab/cocoapods-pod-merge ?

Comment: thanks @PeterStajger. Will give that a try